# Get a 404 error accessing localhost:<port>/manager/html on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, geoserver, ckan

I am aware there are many posts similar to this one, but so far I have not found an answer to my problem. I have very little experience with tomcat.

So this is what I am faced with:

- I created an Ubuntu 14.04 VM on oracle virtualbox
- I installed 2.7 CKAN from package, it is running fine, accessible on `localhost:8080`
- I have a requirement to run Geoserver on the same machine, just for demo purposes
- To deploy the geoserver WAR file I (re)installed tomcat7, no errors
- Default port 8080 was already being used, so I changed this from 8080 to 8095 in `server.xml`
- Included the user with rights to the manager.gui in the `tomcat-users-xml` as is well documented in multiple posts
- Restarted, no issues, can access `localhost:8095` and get the "It works" page.

BUT: when trying to access the `localhost:8095/manager/html` page I get a 404 error.

I have seen multiple posts about a "webapps" folder in the tomcat7 folder, but I do not have this. Reinstall did not install this.

I do not really have a requirement to use tomcat, any alternative that will host geoserver is acceptible.

Will appreciate any help / guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use the Platform Independent Binary from the [downloads page](http://geoserver.org/release/stable/). Just unpack the zip file and you will have a working jetty install with GeoServer ready to go. In your case you will need to change the port jetty uses by editing `start.ini` and look for the line with 8080 in it. Then just run `bin/start.sh`.

To install GeoServer in tomcat the usual procedure is to copy the `geoserver.war` to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` directory and wait for tomcat to unpack it for you.

If you really need to use the manager gui then I believe you need to add `tomcat7-admin` via the package manager.